Ubuntu C program with embeded Ruby: fatal error: ruby/config.h not found
I'm trying compilation simple as possible C program:
gcc -Wall -O0 -std=c99 -pedantic -pedantic-errors `ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["LIBRUBYARG"]'` -I`ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'` -I. -o test test.c

In file included from /usr/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:15,
                 from /usr/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby.h:38,
/usr/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/config.h:22:10: fatal error:     ruby/config.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
 22 | #include "ruby/config.h"
    |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.

#include "ruby.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ruby_init();
  return ruby_cleanup(0);
}

Similar code compiling on fedora.
How typing good options for cc compiler.

So, is there a file  ruby/config.h relative to any directory in the tree rooted at /usr/include/ruby-3.2.0?

To compile Ruby library inside a C program with GCC we need to pass three addition flags to gcc.

rubyhdrdir to be used with -I to add an include path
rubyarchhdrdir to be used with -I to add an include path
LIBRUBYARG to link our dynamic libruby.

In my Debian 12 machine to have a complete development tool chains I installed below packages.
apt install ruby ruby-dev

After that to find three above flag run simple ruby script.
find.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'shellwords'

# location of ruby.h
hdrdir = Shellwords.escape RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]

# location of ruby/config.h
archhdrdir = Shellwords.escape RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyarchhdrdir"]

# location of libruby
libdir = RbConfig::CONFIG["LIBRUBYARG"]

# args for GCC
puts "-I#{hdrdir} -I#{archhdrdir} #{libdir} -Wl,-rpath,#{libdir}"


For me here is output
-I/usr/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-3.1.0 -lruby-3.1 -Wl,-rpath,-lruby-3.1

The code so far and compile command is:
hello_ruby.c
#include "ruby.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ruby_init();

    return ruby_cleanup(0);
}


Consider express your source code before other compile option, I don't know why buy if you put it at end its not work.
gcc -o hello_ruby hello_ruby.c -Wall -I/usr/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-3.1.0 -lruby-3.1

Or more general way is to run our find.rb script to obtain compiler flags.
$ gcc -o hello_ruby hello_ruby.c -Wall $(ruby find.rb)

Another way to find ruby library is run
$ apt install pkg-config
$ pkg-config --libs ruby
-lruby-3.1 -lm 

So a one liner answer would be
gcc -o hello_ruby hello_ruby.c $(pkg-config --cflags ruby) $(pkg-config --libs ruby)

Which I grabbed it from this answer

To sum up my answer I add a simple print message to original source code
The code so far
#include "ruby.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ruby_init();

    if (ruby_setup())
    {
        puts("Hola!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }

    return ruby_cleanup(0);
}

Compile and run in one liner
$ gcc -o hello_ruby hello_ruby.c $(pkg-config --cflags ruby) $(pkg-config --libs ruby); ./hello_ruby 
Hello World


I want to express my answer totally based on below links and answers

Compiling Ruby C API (cross-platform)

Running Ruby in C

another good answer


